# Can physical address of the object residing on heap be zero?

Tags: .net

I was asked this question which says: Can physical address of the object residing on heap be zero? in c# .Net.I am new to this.Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Define what *you* mean by physical address.

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: The address in the RAM where the object will be stored is what i feel.

Comment: @vinaysingri You are aware that the address in RAM can (and in most cases, will) change over time, as an artefact of virtual memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, an address can not be zero. The value zero is used for `null`.

Note that an address for an object on the heap is not actually a physical address, it's an address in the virtual memory space for the process. An object only have a physical address if it happens to be loaded into RAM at the moment, an object can also exist in the page file on disk.